# Selected page not reset when changing search parameters

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav

**How to reproduce**:

- Go to the [main page](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&tagFilter=all&sort=newest&show=all).
- Scroll to the bottom of the page and go to the last page.
- Click on Filter > Custom Tags > Add any tag you want and hit enter.

**Expected result**:

Only questions with the specified tag(s) are displayed, and I'm taken to page 1 of the new search.

**Actual result**:

Only questions with the specified tag(s) are displayed, but you stay on page X.

**Problem**:

This is not much of an issue when searching through normal questions, as the paging bar will still be displayed at the bottom, letting you jump to a valid page:

[image]

However, it is more of an issue when the new search only has exactly one page (as is often the case with bounties), in which case no paging bar is displayed:

[image]

Since we're developers, we can of course manually "fix" this by changing the URL, but this still looks like a bug to me, and I'd like to report it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been made obsolete by the new release.